# vb6 printer.print does not work in vb.net 201

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

Receive this error in build

Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.TabInfo'

This is the line, what do I have to do to make this valid (which does work in vb6)

```
Printer.Print("ATICTS PROBLEM REPORT: " _ 
& txtCallId.Text & FileSystem.TAB(70) & "Hours to date:" _
& FileSystem.TAB(90) & txtHours.Text)
```

Comment: What is `FileSystem`? If it is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem`, then what is `TAB`?

Comment: There is a PowerPack that provides an implementation of the Visual Basic 6.0 Printer object for use in projects upgraded to Visual Basic. Please note, this namespace enables Visual Basic 6.0 Printer code to run without modification in an upgraded project; it is not intended for new development. For new development, use the PrintDocument component. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.compatibility.vb6.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it and thanks for the QUICK answer.

Comment: I also found out that if you add .ToString() after the tab(xx) it allows if to be joined as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you break that up...

```
 Printer.Print("ATICTS PROBLEM REPORT: ")
 Printer.Print(txtCallId.Text)
 Printer.Print(FileSystem.TAB(70))
 Printer.Print("Hours to date:")
 Printer.Print(FileSystem.TAB(90))
 Printer.Print(txtHours.Text)
```

As understand it, FileSystem.Tab wasn't a simple tab character or number of spaces.  I believe the above has the best chance of producing the same results.